# Safe to remove /usr/local/bin/node?

Tags: apt, uninstall, nodejs

In the past I installed Node.js. Now I tried updating it following [this guide](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#installation-instructions) and ended up having two versions of it, `node` on version 0.10.7 and `nodejs` on version 0.12.7. To clear this up I wanted to remove it completely and reinstall it. `apt-get remove nodejs` worked fine, but not `apt-get remove node`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'node' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

But:

```
$ which node
/usr/local/bin/node
```

Is it safe to remove this file or will I have leftovers lurking around somewhere else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It is safe to remove `/usr/local/bin/node` folder but you have to remove or edit Nodejs from the PATH in ~/.bashrc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! One more question, though: In my `.bashrc` there is no mention of `node`. After removing the file and reinstallation of Node.js `which node` now returns `/usr/bin/node` which is fine, but typing just `node` results in `bash: /usr/local/bin/node: No such file or directory`. Any idea?

Comment: @hielsnoppe Check also: `/etc/environment` and `~/.profile`

Comment: No `node` there either. :(

Comment: @hielsnoppe Run `hash -r` and try again.

Answer (score 5):

you are installing node from binaries which is self installation (not using ubuntu software center).

When you do self installation of node usually you create a symbolic link to /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin to put in the path for everyone system-wide.

If you installed new version of node all you have to do is to remove the symlink of the old one and place the new one instead.

```
 ln -s /path/where/node/installed/bin/node /usr/bin/node
```

Remove of course the one in /usr/local/bin or /usr/bin before.